# JQuery url GET variable

Tags: php, jquery

I there a possible way to use a `GET` variable in jQuery url. Like in PHP we have something like this:

```
header('location : path/to/page.php?id='.$id);
```

And In the page.php we do this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

So in jQuery can we do something like:

```
window.location.replace(path/to/page.html/* and pass the url query here*/);
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: you want to rewrite the path `path/to/page.php?id=?` to `path/to/page.html` why not use htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to access the query string ($_GET in php) variables in javascript. You can use this function for that.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

and then call `getParameterByName('id')` to get `?id=val` part of the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass data to another page using location.replace:

```
 idVal = 1;
 window.location.replace("path/to/page.php?id="+idVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a js function to do this...

```
   var getUrlVars = function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(decodeURIComponent(hash[0]));
            vars[decodeURIComponent(hash[0])] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
        }
        if(vars[0] == window.location.href){
            vars =[];
        }
        return vars;
    }
```

Then where ever you wish to use

```
var params = getUrlVars();
console.log(params["id"]);
console.log(params["whatever"]);
```

You can use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

the property 'search' of the 'location' javascript object will give you the querystring parameters of the url, eg:

url:  http://www.w3schools.com/submit.htm?email=someone@example.com

```
console.log(location.search);
// output: ?email=someone@example.com
```

after that you can parse it as you wish